# List Comprehensions - How to have strings and integers in one list?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I apologise for the complexity of this question, but it is a massive challenge for me being very new to Python:

I have an external file that stores lines of text: `input.txt`

```
min: 1,2,3,5,6
max: 1,2,3,5,6
avg: 1,2,3,5,6
```

I read the content of the file into various lists in a new variable called `input_data` like this:

```
input_data = []
with open('input.txt') as inputfile:
    for line in inputfile:
        input_data.append(line.strip().split(','))
```

The result for `input_data` is as follows:

```
[['min: 1', '2', '3', '5', '6'], ['max: 1', '2', '3', '5', '6'], ['avg: 1', '2', '3', '5', '6']]
```

So I have one variable with 3 lists stored in it.

How do I remove the ":" after 'min', 'max' and 'avg'?

I have tried:

```
input_data = input_data.replace(":",",")
```

Also, how do I keep `min`, `max` and `avg` as strings, but change the numbers in the lists to integers? eg.

```
['min', 1, 2, 3, 5, 6]
```

'min' string and all numbers integers

Comment: This looks as if a dictionary might be the better datastructure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just split on the colon then map the rest to int after splitting on a comma:

```
with open("in.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        a, rest = line.split(":",1)
        print([a] + map(int,rest.split(",")))
```

Output:

```
['min', 1, 2, 3, 5, 6]
['max', 1, 2, 3, 5, 6]
['avg', 1, 2, 3, 5, 6]
```

Comment: @Lee, no worries, glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

```
input_data = []
with open('input.txt') as inputfile:
    for line in inputfile:
        row = []
        sections = line.strip().split(':')  # First split out the title
        kind = sections[0]
        row.append(kind)
        data = sections[1].split(',')
        for entry in data:
            row.append(int(entry))  # Use int to convert to integer
        input_data.append(row)
```

Try that. First I just split the line using the colon `:`. The first part is the headers ('min', 'max' and 'avg'), which I add to my new 'row' of output data.

Then I split the second part (the numbers) the exact same way that you did. I then used the [built in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) [int](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) to convert string numbers into actual integer values.

I made the code very explicit so you should be able to understand every line!

If you actually wanted to make a list comprehension, the (very ugly) direct translation of my code above looks like this:

```
with open('input.txt') as f:
    result = [[line.split(':')[0]] + [int(x) for x in line.split(':')[1].split(',')] for line in f]
```

Answer (score 1):

To start with, I'd suggest split it differently. To keep the word and first value separated, convert the space to a comma so it'll split correctly. In this case, you could probably convert ": " to a comma so it'll automatically remove the colon.

```
input_data = line.strip().replace(': ', ',').split(',')
```

Then to convert all necessary values to integers, you could do it in loads of ways, but here's two examples:

```
input_data = [input_data[0]] + [int(i) for i in input_data[1:]]
input_data = [int(i) for i if i.isdigit() else i for i in input_data]
```

Alternatively if you didn't do the bit at the start and still have a colon, this is how you could get rid of it with a tweak to one of the above methods:

```
input_data = [int(i) for i if i.isdigit() else i.replace(':', '') for i in input_data]
```

And finally, this should hopefully work with your code:

```
input_data = []
with open('input.txt') as inputfile:
    for line in inputfile:
        input_data.append([int(i) for i if i.isdigit() else i for i in line.strip().split(',')])
```

Or if needed, a slightly shorter version:

```
with open('input.txt') as inputfile:
    input_data = [[int(i) for i if i.isdigit() else i for i in line.strip().split(',')] for line in inputfile]
```

Symmitchry's answer is probably a bit better though, splitting it into the two seconds didn't cross my mind.

Comment: Thank you Peter, I appreciate your time and answer, I can make use of it for sure.